# Cancel open bounty to a question by moderator?(with lost reputation)

Tags: discussion

If a user puts in an open bounty and found the question is not possible to implement and it's not important reputation either not matter for him/her, could I ask the moderator to delete question and close open bounty (with lost reputation)?

I ask it because I remember putting in an open bounty for a question and because some user voted it was too board the open bounty canceled (and in that case the reputation went back to my reputation sum).

Comment: Have you seen such a situation?  I'm not sure I've seen a person want an answer enough to offer a bounty to then later decide they don't care anymore.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure. It's not unheard of for the author to solve the problem themselves, for example.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, the developer found that _question is not possible to implement_ and want to do that

Comment: Meta commentry on a question should be avoided. It doesn't help anyone else reading it later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you flag the question *immediately* after putting the bounty on because you put the bounty on by accident (for example because you meant to put it on a different question), and didn't mean to, a moderator *may* choose to (although aren't obligated to) remove the bounty, if it's caught early enough, and people haven't started posting answers for the bounty.

If it's been a while, then "I don't care about the answer any more" isn't a valid reason to revoke the bounty, no.

Comment: I mean that the developer found _question is not possible to implement_ after 2 or 3 day and its better to close or delete the question

Comment: @combo_ci That's not a reason to close to delete a question.  That's an answer to the question.

Comment: and whats about that the author of question want to delete question anyway?

Comment: @combo_ci If, after the bounty ends, the post is still eligible for author self-deletion, they're welcome to delete it.  (It would almost be impossible for that to happen, but it's possible.)  If, by the time the bounty ends, there is a well received answer or multiple answers (which is likely) then they wouldn't be able to delete it, and "I want to delete it even though it's a perfectly fine question) isn't likely to persuade a moderator to delete it.